# Get Hashtable Key of similar content but not reference

Tags: java, hashtable

I have some java code that looks like this: it uses a `Hashtable` to store data that corresponds to a three-dimensional point.

```
Hashtable<ThreeDimensionalPoint,data> table = new Hashtable<ThreeDimensionalPoint,data>();
table.put(new ThreeDimensionlPoint(1,1,1),new data());
table.get(new ThreeDimensionalPoint(1,1,1);
```

What I want to do is to get `data` back out of the hashtable, only knowing the coordinates of the `ThreeDimensionalPoint` object. Of course, the third line will not work, since `.get` matches keys by reference, not content of the object.

Does anybody have a solution?the `ThreeDimensionalPoint`class has three integers that specify the coordinates.

Comment: You need to override the equals and hashCode methods in the ThreeDimensionalPoint class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your `ThreeDimensionalPoint` class.

Assuming that the properties of your `ThreeDimensionalPoint` are the dimensions (x, y, z), the following is an example generated from IntelliJ Idea.

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Coordinate that = (Coordinate) o;

    if (x != that.x) return false;
    if (y != that.y) return false;
    return z == that.z;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = x;
    result = 31 * result + y;
    result = 31 * result + z;
    return result;
}
```

> When you are overriding `equals` and `hashCode`, you should keep in
>   mind that,
>
> (1) If your `equals` method returns that two objects are the same then
>   your `hashCode` must return the same code for both of them. Otherwise,
>   you will see unpredictable behavior in your Hashtable.
>
> (2) Although not required, if your `equals` method returns that two
>   objects are unequal then,`hashCode` should try to generate two
>   different value for these two objects. This helps to achieve better
>   performance.

Comment: *"if your equals method returns that two objects are unequal then, your hashCode must generate two different value for these two objects."* that part of your statement is untrue. It is impossible to have a hash code  that never will have two unequal objects be the same value due to the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). It is ***preferred*** that two unequal objects will have different hash codes, as that leads to better performance on your lookups, but it is not ***required***.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals and hashcode methods in your class ThreeDimensionalPoint, like this example (feel free to adjust it to your exact code):

```
class ThreeDimensionalPoint 
{

    public int cord1;
    public int cord2;
    public int cord3;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        // checking if both the object references are 
        // referring to the same object.
        if(this == obj)
            return true;

        // it checks if the argument is of the 
        // type ThreeDimensionalPoint by comparing the classes 
        // of the passed argument and this object.
        if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass())
            return false;

        // type casting of the argument. 
        ThreeDimensionalPoint threeDPoint = (ThreeDimensionalPoint) obj;

        // comparing the state of argument with 
        // the state of 'this' Object.
        return (threeDPoint.cord1 == this.cord1 && threeDPoint.cord2 == this.cord2 && threeDPoint.cord3 == this.cord3);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 31 * hash + cord1;
        hash = 31 * hash + cord2;
        hash = 31 * hash + cord3;

        return hash;
    }

}
```

You can find more information of this example at this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but instead of using the object as a key, since you are only tracing 3 coordinates, why not make a string as key?

Instead of

```
Hashtable<ThreeDimensionalPoint,data> table = new Hashtable<ThreeDimensionalPoint,data>();
table.put(new ThreeDimensionlPoint(1,1,1),new data());
table.get(new ThreeDimensionalPoint(1,1,1));
```

Why not

```
String tag = 1 + "-" + 1 + "-" + 1; // making it "1-1-1"
Hashtable<String,data> table = new Hashtable<String,data>();
table.put(tag,new data());
table.get("1-1-1");
```

Comment: That works too, and I was considering doing that, but for a program that does thousands of these lookups every second, it wont't be very efficient.